# How to make the SharePoint Solution Deployer (SPSD) continue to next script on error?

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment

I am using SPSD (SharePoint Solution Deployer) to run all my deployment scripts and when I run into an error in one script, the entire process gets interrupted and the following scripts are not executed. How can I make SPSD to continue executing other scripts?